# Ubuntu generated new mysql configs

Tags: mysql

I deleted `/etc/mysql`, everything in it.

I tried:

```
apt-get --purge remove mysql-server
```

Then:

```
apt-get install mysql-server
```

They will not return, how do I get them to?

There seems to be some very specific config the files need to use upstarts `service mysql start` including some debian-sys-maint (or something) config settings... wish it was a simple as making a `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` but its not.

Answer (score 2):

/etc/mysql/my.cnf isn't owned by the mysql-server package.  It's owned by mysql-common (I used `dpkg -S /etc/mysql/my.cnf` to find this out).

This should work for you:

`apt-get purge mysql-common` (which will also remove mysql-server)

And then:

`apt-get install mysql-server` (which, of course, will pull in mysql-common and should repopulate your /etc/mysql directory).